# I can't publish to my Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.3 jelly bean) from Flash

Tags: android, flash, publish

I have Adobe Flash CS6, and an Android Samsung Galaxy S3 (4.3) phone. I can't publish from Flash, even though I have USB debugging enabled and allow mock locations enabled. I don't know how to install the apk otherwise. Please help!

Comment: Ugh why wont anyone answer D:

Comment: What does 'I cant publish' mean? Device is not detected (if so, did you try 'adb devices' command)? Some error occures?

Comment: Well, you kind of have to know how flash air publishing works to answer this question. My phone said I have to sync it with a program called Samsung kies 3, I did that, nothing happened. I tried reinstalling the driver too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to publish/install the apk without having the phone tethered? Can you manually install the apk file?

In Android I believe there is a setting that enables you to install apk files not from the marketplace etc. which could be directly from a web download or an sd card.

Comment: I have. By the way a long time has passed since I have tested that, a lot of fixes came. It might work by now, but the way I installed my apk's is I just uploaded them to dropbox and installed it from dropbox on my phone